# Line integral and attraction of a material point by a material curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: analysis, line-integrals

According to Newton's law of universal gravitation, a material point $P$ with mass $m$ attracts a material point $P_0$ with mass $m_0$ with a force directed from $P_0$ towards $P$, of size $k\cfrac{mm_0}{r^2}$ (further for simplicity k=1).

Note that when the point $P_0$ (located at the point $(0, 0, 0)$) of mass $m_0$,
is attracted by the point $P_i$ (located in the point $(x_i, y_i, z_i)$) of mass $m_i$,
is the force acting between them we express as
$$\dfrac{m_om_i}{r_i^3}(x_i,y_i,z_i),$$
where $r_i=\sqrt{(x_i^2+y_i^2+z_i^2)}$.

In the situation where the point $P_0$ is attracted by points $P_1, P_2, \ldots, P_n$ with masses $m_1, m_2,\ldots,m_n$ and the attracting mass has a continuous distribution on the curve $\sigma:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3, \sigma(t)=(\sigma_1(t),\sigma_2(t),\sigma_3(t))$, the curve is divided into small segments by points $a=t_0<t_1<\ldots<t_n=b$. Then we write the force of attraction as the sum of the vectors

$$F=\sum_i \dfrac{m_0m_i}{r_i(\sigma(t_i))}(\sigma_1(t_i),\sigma_2(t_i),\sigma_3(t_i)).$$

Also
$$m_i=\int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i}f(\sigma_1(t_i),\sigma_2(t_i),\sigma_3(t_i))\sqrt{\sigma_1'(t_i)^2+\sigma_2'(t_i)^2+\sigma_3'(t_i)^2}dt.$$

Then
$$F=\sum_i \dfrac{m_0\cdot \int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i}f(\sigma_1(t_i),\sigma_2(t_i),\sigma_3(t_i))\sqrt{\sigma_1'(t_i)^2+\sigma_2'(t_i)^2+\sigma_3'(t_i)^2}dt}{r_i(\sigma(t_i))}(\sigma_1(t_i),\sigma_2(t_i),\sigma_3(t_i)).$$

**How to show that this sum goes to a vector value integral? How to find this integral?**

Comment: Do you mean "integral"? "Integers" are numbers with no fractional part. That is a concept unrelated to "vectors". If you mean "Integral", then what you described is a Riemann sum for integration of the force vector along the curve. So yes, as the partition size $\to 0$, the sum will converge to the integral along the curve.

Comment: @PaulSinclair yes … I mean integral. Do you know how to find this integral?

Comment: So you are discretizing it here, but you say that there is a continuous mass distribution. So, yes, you get a line integral giving the force as $$\vec F = m_0\int_C f(\vec x)\frac{\vec x}{\|\vec x\|^3}\,ds.$$ (It appears you dropped the exponent in the denominator.) When you parametrize, you get $$m_0\int_a^b f(\sigma(t))\frac{\vec\sigma(t)}{\|\vec\sigma(t)\|^3}\|\vec\sigma{}'(t)\|dt.$$

Comment: @TedShifrin can we prove it that this sum will converge to this integral?

Comment: Just as one does any Riemann sum converging to an integral. Nothing unusual here.